# CSS Footer Not on same Line

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

Im trying to write a footer like this one

[image]

Did i said that im very bad at Css?

My css looks like this

```
#footer-navi
{
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
    padding-bottom:1.5em;
}
clearfix
{
    display:block;
}

#footer-group
{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**EDIT:**  Here is some html

```
<div id="footer-group">
         <ul id="footer-navi" class="clearfix">
           <li> 
            <h4>Products</h4> 
              <ul>
               <li><a href="#">test 1</a><li>
              </ul>


            <h4>Products 2</h4>
            <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">test 2</a><li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

How can i implement somethin like the footer above? 
Thanks very much.

Comment: You should post up some HTML too :)

Comment: I'm guessing you want a "." before "clearfix".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this HTML:

```
<div id="footer-navi">
    <ul>
        <li>Kaufen<ul>
            <li>ein</li>
            <li>zwei</li>
            <li>drei</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Verkaufen<ul>
            <li>ein</li>
            <li>zwei</li>
            <li>drei</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#footer-navi ul {
    font-size: 75%;
}
#footer-navi>ul {
    font-size: 150%;
}
#footer-navi>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See it: http://jsfiddle.net/AGL4N/
It needs formatting (margin, padding, line-height, font-size, etc) but the basic idea that you want is there.